# Verilog Continuous Simulation

Tags: verilog, modelsim

Are there special start and end keywords in verilog that will allow a simulation to continue running until an end keyword is met? I understand this would not be synthesizable; however, I only wish to use it for testing purposes. Also the $finish keyword in verilog exits modelsim.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$finish` and `$stop` are the verilog system tasks to stop simulation. `$finish` terminates the simulation whereas `$stop` stops the simulation and goes to interactive mode. So you can use `$stop`. Even `$finish` should be fine since ModelSim usually asks whether you want to finish. Choose 'no' to stay in simulation mode, choosing 'yes' will exit ModelSim.